# Why can't I just write an execution plan directly instead of SQL?

Tags: sql, performance

I've always had this problem that went like this:

- Have a slow SQL query that needs to be faster
- Be confused why it's slow
- Look at execution plan
- Realize why it is slow
- Know exactly what changes to the execution plan would likely result in a faster query
- Attempt to formulate SQL query to get desired execution plan
- Repeat previous step ~20 times
- Learn to live with a slow query

This is not asking how to formulate the query from a desired plan, since that depends on the situation. The question is: **Why bother?**

Sure, for simple queries the execution plan is something I don't really care about or want to think about. But for complex queries, it feels like I'm programming in brainf*ck. I don't mean to brag, but I do believe I am much better at formulating execution plans than the optimizer is. Not only that, but it's an extra step to slow everything down more. The optimizer can't know many things than I know. It always feels like I'm fighting it as opposed to working with it.

I've looked online best I could, and there seems to be no way to write an execution plan directly, although I could have missed something.

#### Why do we write SQL queries instead of writing execution plans directly?

<sup><sub>Side note: In SQLite, it's always baffled me that despite running *in the same process* as the program querying, SQLite still asks for a textual, character-array query and then has to parse it. In the cases of dymanic query generation, this means the query is generated and then immediately parsed by the same process.</sub></sup>

Comment: go write your own DBMS. Profit.

Comment: @Shel - I think you ask a decent question. One that would probably generate some interesting discussion. The problem is you clearly demonstrate a bias against and a frustration towards the way things work and yet you are unaware of the historical reasons for why things work the way they do. It's arrogant and it discourages a discussion before it can even start.

Comment: I think you can easily imagine why DBMS companies have no desire to support that -- you may be mr. super programmer -- but look at some of the questions on this site -- there are a whole lot of programmers who have trouble getting the simplest things right.

Comment: @Jeremy Usually when I have an idea like this theres a vital I'm missing that makes the whole thing pointless and/or impossible, which is part of why I'm asking this.

Comment: I don't understand those who down-voted this question. Although, I think that answers are simple: a) people are lazy - nobody (myself included) don't want to write plans for **every** sql query, b) modern sql engines have very effective query planners and can give a handycap for 80% of programmers, c) effective plans change with time with changes in data.

Comment: I didn't down-vote this, but I find it amusing that people seem surprised.  This question is pretty clearly outside the bounds of stackoverflow - especially since there is no clear answer and it will probably elicit endless discussion.  Note: I'm not saying it's a dumb question or that you're an idiot for asking - I'm just saying that this isn't the place for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because SQL is a fifth generation programming language (the only successful one I know of) - it's main feature is that it writes the code for you.  It inspects the contents of the database and determines the best way to do things.

That said, there are ways to manually change the execution plan on the fly via RECOMPILE.  However, I suggest you stick to using HINTS rather than trying to do anything overly fancy.  Generally, the planner does a better job than you possibly could.

One common way to solve consistently slow execution plans is to add [WITH RECOMPILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx) to the end of your query.  It causes the execution plan to be recompiled each time you execute it - not great for memory performance, but it is worth testing to see if it improves a highly active (many reads/writes) database.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a declarative language and its sole purpose is to help you write declarative code. You have to simply tell what you want to achieve. Then onwards it is the language's responsibility to figure out the best way to achieve it. Because the language still isn't that advanced, users often have to "know exactly what changes to the execution plan would likely result in a faster query". The ideal declarative language would perfectly decipher user's intentions.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can use optimizer hint USE PLAN which allow to you give to SQL Server your best execution plan. Also, there any other optimizer hints like specifying physical joins, optimizing for some parameters, using specific table join and others. Yes, you can give best execution plan **on current moment**. But you maybe will have problems in the future because data changes. You can add indexes on table columns, drop it, distribution of data in the columns can changed. Your best plan now can be worst plan in the future. SQL engine will calculate **good** plan in the any case maybe it won't **best**.

SQL query is something like abstraction which allows not to think about best execution plan. It is our advantage not drawback.